# Get all resources available in a resourcegroup using Azure Java SDK

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-java-sdk

Hi I'm trying to getresourceNames available within a resourcegroup from Azure Java SDK. but couldn't find a proper method for the same.

```
ArrayList<ResourceGroupExtended> groups = resourceManagementClient.getResourceGroupsOperations().list(null).getResourceGroups();
 for (GenericResourceExtended genericResourceExtended : resourceList) {

    System.out.println( "genericResourceExtended Name :"+genericResourceExtended.getName()); 
               }
```

Please share me your idea if you tried the same. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    ArrayList<ResourceGroupExtended> groups = client.getResourceGroupsOperations().list(null).getResourceGroups();
    for (ResourceGroupExtended group : groups) {
        System.out.println(group.getName());
        ResourceListParameters resListParams = new ResourceListParameters();
        resListParams.setResourceGroupName(group.getName());
        ArrayList<GenericResourceExtended> resList = client.getResourcesOperations().list(resListParams).getResources();
        for(GenericResourceExtended r: resList) {
            System.out.println("Resource Type: "+r.getType()+" name: "+r.getName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: May I know in whiich package "ResourceGroupExtended" is available in ?